# Pasar datos de Python a Excel

Tags: python, excel

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo Python y estoy empezando a encontrarme con pequeñas dificultades que me gustaría aclarar.

por ejemplo, en este sencillo loop:

```
post=''
for i in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9:
    if i > 2:
        post = str(post) + str(i)    
print(post)
```

que nos devuelve una serie de números mayores que 2.

Para pasarlos a la hoja Excel lo he realizado así:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATOS': [post]})
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\USUARIO\Downloads\ej.xlsx")
```

Pero. ¿cómo podría pasarlos número a número en varias filas de la primera columna de la hoja Excel?. Es decir, en cada iteración pasar el número a A2, A3, A4, etc)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestranos tus intentos por favor, tu codigo o similar. Modifica la pregunta y solo pon una, despues abres otra con la otra pregunta porfa.

Comment: Disculpa, ya he modificado la consulta. Finalmente he conseguido solucionar el problema del primer tipo de exportación. Me queda la segunda duda. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera para rellenar hojas excel puede ser con `openpyxl`.

No sé exactamente qué números quieres poner en cada celda, pero te pongo un ejemplo que te servirá para adaptarlo a tu caso:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for fila in range(2,10): #Itera entre los números del 2 al 9
    ws['A' + str(fila)] = fila # En A2 pone un 2, en A3 pone un 3, etc.

# Guarda el archivo en la ruta que le digas
wb.save(r"Ruta_Archivo/Archivo.xlsx")
```

Otra manera para indicarle el numero de celda y de columna, mucho más cómodo para mi gusto que ir poniendo la letra de la columna, sería sustituir el bucle `for` por este:

```
for fila in range(2,10):
    ws.cell(row=fila, column=1, value=fila)
```

En ambos casos te devolvería un archivo excel con lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes modificar los bucles para introducir los datos que necesites en las casillas que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que tu dato `post` es una cadena, y no una lista.

Al terminar tu bucle, la variable `post` contiene la cadena `"3456789", que es un solo dato y no varios. Al convertirlo en dataframe con pandas, el dataframe resultante tendrá una sola celda con ese dato:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATOS': [post]})
print(df)

-----

     DATOS
0  3456789
```

Entiendo que tú querrías los números uno debajo de otro, cada uno en su celda. Para ello a pandas tienes que pasarle una lista en la que cada elemento sería el valor que va a una celda. Por tanto tu bucle debería haber sido:

```
post= []
for i in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9:  # Aqui podrías haber puesto for i in range(1,10):
    if i > 2:
        post.append(i)
```

En este caso `post` sería al final la lista: `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` y para crear el dataframe pandas usarías `post` sin corchetes (pues ya él es una lista):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATOS': post})
```

resultando en:

```
   DATOS
0      3
1      4
2      5
3      6
4      7
5      8
6      9
```

Eso ya lo puedes exportar como excel.

### Nota

Si lo que buscabas era un dataframe en el que las dos primeras filas estuvieran vacía (para que en la excel las casillas A1 y A2 quede en blanco), basta que pongas `None` o una cadena vacía en los elementos de la lista en los que desees casillas vacías. Por ejemplo:

```
post = []
for i in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9:
      if i > 2:
        post.append(i)
      else:
        post.append("")
```

Ten en cuenta no obstante que pandas comienza numerando sus filas con el índice 0, mientras que excel lo hace con el índice 1. En el dataframe resultante en este ejemplo las dos primeras filas estarán vacías, que son las filas de índice 0 y 1. En la excel que te sale si exportas el dataframe, también las dos primeras filas estarán vacías, pero excel las llama A1 y A2. Tenlo en cuenta, según qué desees hacer.